# Change the Space between UIBarButton Items to be zero?

Tags: uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I have CustomImage UIButtons as my UIBarButtonItems. The way the Graphic designer made the Images, they are made to butt up against each other and not have a 10px or so gap between them. Is there a way to remove the gap between the UIBarButtonItems when adding them to the UIToolBar?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So Fiddling around, I was able to get something to work. Though I'm not 100% sure I understand why.   If I pass in an Image that is wide, (Greater than 15+px) it works fine, through if I put in an Image that is 1px wide, I cannot get it to work.  What I'm looking for is something like:

```
<image> | <Image> | <image> |    <flex space>       | <image> | <Image> | <image>
```

Though I didn't want to create the Images with the `|` in them, so I have a Image that is just the `|` separator. When adding that Button, I cannot get the gap between them to close. I fiddled with the frame and Inset values to no avail.

This is what I have for the wider buttons:

```
-(id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title normalImage:(UIImage *)normalImage highlightedImage:(UIImage *)highlightedImage selectedImage:(UIImage *)selectedImage target:(id)target action:(SEL)action {

button =  [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setImage:normalImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setImage:highlightedImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[button setImage:selectedImage forState:UIControlStateSelected];
[button addTarget:target action:action forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 74, 48)];

// This is the code that seemed to make it work 
// Though not 100% sure why
// - - - - -
UIEdgeInsets buttonInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, -5, 0, -5);
button.contentEdgeInsets = buttonInset;
[button sizeToFit];
button.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
// - - - - -

buttonLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 30, 74, 17)];
buttonLabel.opaque = NO;
buttonLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
buttonLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0f];
buttonLabel.text = title;
buttonLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
[button addSubview:buttonLabel];
[buttonLabel release];

    // create a UI
self = [super initWithCustomView:button];
[self setStyle:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered];

return self;

}
```